# Beautiful Soup - getting tag contents

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The html code I have (multiple of these entries) looks like this:

```
<p class="number-values">
    <span class="text">Count:</span>
    <span data-value="10000" name="nv">10,000</span>
    <span class="devider">#</span> <span class="text">Number:</span>
    <span data-value="500,000" name="nv">0.05</span>
</p>
```

Now, I'm looking to get the content of the data-value tags. What I've written so far is:

```
url = http://example.com
source = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,"lxml")

contents = soup.find_all("p", class_="number-values")

for content in contents:
    print(content.string)
```

However it outputs this (including a lot of senseless returns I couldn't figure out):

```
Count:

10,000

#

Number:

0,05
```

I can't seem to find the right tag to extract, maybe I should regex the entire string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does make sense , because you gave him the class for `p` tag it returns all text of its child tags . if you want just `10,000` and`0,05` you should search through span tags with have attribute `name = "nv"` :

```
for content in soup.find_all("span" , {"name" : "nv"}):
    print (content.text) # 10,000 0,05
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
contents = soup.find_all("p", {"class":"number-values"})
```